# Does leaving a new job because I'm moving look bad?

Tags: resume, resignation, retail

I work a retail job in a general store. 
I'm a teenager. 
I'm going into my first year of college in a few weeks.

When I started work, I thought I'd be able to stay and have my hours reduced for when I started classes. However, I realized that I'll have issues with both commuting and living with my family, so I want to move out.  I found a place to stay near my university, and I'm all set on moving out because I think I'd do better in school that way.

The problem is that I've only been working at the store for three weeks now. I have less than two weeks until I'm supposed to move in. As for work experience -- I've done internships, but this is my first true job. School is definitely my number one priority at the moment.

If it will look bad on my resume, the only other option I can think of is transferring. I wouldn't want to work closing in the area because it's dangerously sketchy and I'd have to walk home.

Is it understandable that I'm leaving after working for such a brief amount of time?

Is it acceptable to list this on my resume?

Comment: What are you going to college for/what do you plan to do afterwards? Retail work may be irrelevant for whatever you end up doing in the future anyway. Have you considered looking for an on-campus job, as well?

Comment: If the store is part of a chain/franchise/etc it may be worth looking into the possibility of being transfered to the same chain/franchise/etc in the same location as your college. I have no personal experience with this but a friend of mine working for a major fast-food chain got such a transfer when he went to college and all parties involved were happy with the new arrangement.

Answer (score 10):

> I work a retail job in a general store. I'm a teenager. I'm going into my first year of college in a few weeks.

A few things here which make it not a factor:

- You are a teenager, your college experience is way more important than your high school jobs. Having a job period is what is important there, not why you quit
- You are going to college, most people expect that to be moved.

  - The job is also likely irrelevant to your post-college ambitions

> If it will look bad on my resume
>   Is it acceptable to list this on my resume?

I wouldn't even list it. A ~5 week job is more than irrelevant anyways.

You do not *have* to list all jobs on your resume. You *might* have to add this depending on how comprehensive of a job application you fill out but in general, I wouldn't worry about this at all.

I suspect your anxiety about having to let down people who just hired you is causing you to assume everyone reading a resume will care the same - which they won't (well, maybe if you apply to that company again... :-).

Comment: Good answer, except for the mismatched parenthesis at the end. Yeah, I have OCD for that.)

Comment: @MaskedMan https://xkcd.com/859/

Answer (score 2):

If you are still at school that is what goes into your CV. Don´t even bother to list the retail job, unless you apply somewhere where you think your experince there is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You are a student and most employers will understand short term work for students. People often work for a few months on their months off of school and then go back school full time when classes start back up and leave work. Or in your case moving for school is also fine.

As long as your resume has stated your time frame for school most employers would understand the short work history. Young people, especially students have a bit more leeway on how long they have worked at jobs.